# Subgroups of order 5 and 6 in a group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

According to my solution, we use Lagrange's Theorem and the fact, that all subgroups of a finite group have an order dividing the order of the group.

As a result, we can say that the orders of the subgroups of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ are $\{1,2,5,10\}$, which means that we can not have a group of order $6$.

Then as for the subgroups of order $5$, we have several subgroups that can be represented as a group of even numbers.

I wonder if my judgment is correct or if there are any other ways to solve that type of questions.

Comment: One part always works : If the order does not divide the group order, there cannot be an element with that order. The converse is not always true, but in this case, it follows from the fact that there is always an element of prime order $p$ if $p$ divides the group order.

Comment: In the special case of a cyclic group (like here) the converse holds as well.

Comment: Note that, in general, it is not true that every number that divides the order of $G$ must be the order of a subgroup: $A_4$ has order $12$, but no subgroup of order $6$. The divisibility property is a **necessary**, but not **sufficient** condition for orders of a subgroup. So when you say “the orders [...] are $\{1,2,5,10\}$”, that is unjustified by what you have quoted. However, it is a theorem that if $G$ is *cyclic* (as is the case here), then $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$ **if and only if** $d$ divides $|G|$.

Comment: Also, if $G$ is finite cyclic, then it has a *unique* subgroup of order $d$ for every $d$ dividing the order of the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the best you can do in solving these problems is doing an "educated" exhaustive search. You are right that a subgroup of order $6$ cannot exist. For a subgroup of order $5$ you have also found that the even numbers work. For this case you can check the rest of the elements and see if they lie in a subgroup of order $5$. It is the odd numbers we need to check.

You can note that $1$, $3$, $7$, and $9$ generate the group, so cannot be contained in a subgroup of order $5$. We have also that $5$ generates a subgroup of order $2$; any subgroup that contains $5$ must contain a subgroup of order $2$, hence cannot be of order $5$ (in fact the only other one is the whole group). Having eliminated all possibilities, we see that the even elements are all that is left.